# How can I convert the following Mathematica code into sympy?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, sympy

I am trying to convert some Mathematica code into python and I didn't know how to handle the following function. Is there a way to go about is using sympy or other python module? TPUV, AM1UV and GUV are vectors computed by other accompanying functions.

```
perpUnitVector[]:=Module[
{sol,a3,b3,c3,a4,b4,c4},
sol=Quiet[Solve[
{a3,b3,c3}.TPUV==0&&  
{a3,b3,c3}.AM1UV==0&&
{a3,b3,c3}.{a3,b3,c3}==1&&
Sign[Cross[-GUV,{a3,b3,c3}].Cross[{1,0,0},-GUV]]>0,
{a3,b3,c3},Reals]];

{a4,b4,c4}=Flatten[{a3,b3,c3}/.sol[[1]],1]
]
```

**Test case:**
With TPU = {1,3,4}, AM1UV = {4, 5, 6}, GUV = {1,1,1}, Mathematica gives
a4 = -0.408248, b4 = 0.816497, and c4 = -0.408248.

**my sympy attempt is here but doesn't seem to work**

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym

GUV = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0];
AM1UV = [4.0, 5.0, 6.0];
TPUV = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0];

a3,b3,c3,a4,b4,c4 = sym.symbols('a3 b3 c3 a4 b4 c4')

sol = sym.solveset(np.dot([a3,b3,c3],TPUV),
            np.dot([a3,b3,c3],AM1UV),
            np.dot([a3,b3,c3],[a3,b3,c3])-1,
            np.sign(np.dot(np.cross(-GUV,[a3,b3,c3]),
            np.cross([1,0,0],-GUV)))>0,
            [a3,b3,c3],S.Reals)
```

Comment: sympy and numpy really don't work well together. You should try to express everything using sympy functions. Also, sympy usually doesn't cope well with floats. Whenever possible try to write them as integers (or as fractions).

Comment: So you look for a normalized vector with specific projection properties? The cross product then selects a specific direction, right? A 1-to-1 translation might not be the best. Some intermediate steps and some `if`s might be better suited.